# pymongo and multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pymongo

I have a 100MB collection that I wish extract. Doing this in a single .find() is not very performant and therefore I would like to use the `multiprocessing` module to parallelize the extraction.

I have a unique field that can be found in multiple documents, and so I can split the collection into `n` chunks based on this field.

```
chunks = [lst[i:i + size] for i in range(0, len(lst), size)]
```

I have a function that returns all the documents in a chunk.

```
def func(chunk):
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(...)
    cursor = collection.find({'field': {'$in': chunk}}, {'_id': 0})
    docs = [doc for doc in cursor]
    return docs
```

I'm not sure how to link everything up using `multiprocessing`. How can I pass all my chunks to the target func?

This doesn't seem to be working:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for chunk in chunks:
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(chunk,))
        proc.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Process in General

To use Process we need a method to pass values between processes like queues.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def func(chunk, queue):
    # do your stuff
    docs = .... 
    #pass the result to the queue
    queue.put(docs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    list_of_processes = []
    for chunk in chunks:
        proc = Process(target=func, args=(chunk, queue,))
        proc.start()
        list_of_processes.append(proc)

# waiting for finishing all processes
    for proc in list_of_processes:
        proc.join()

#recover all results:        
    result_list = []
    while not queue.empty():
        result_list.append(queue.get())
```

### But for PyMongo

I think pooling is better.
See this [How does connection pooling work in PyMongo?](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo)

Pooling in your case:

```
import multiprocessing

def func(chunks):
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(...)
    result_list = []
    for chunk in chunks:
        #do your stuff like collection.find()
        cursor = collection.find({'field': {'$in': chunk}}, {'_id': 0})
        docs = [doc for doc in cursor]
        result_list.append(result)
    return result_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # pool creation
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) #spawn 4 processes
    result = pool.map(func, chunks)
    pool.close()
    # 'result' is a list of lists
```